# FTP Server Connecting via Browser, but not Working in FileZilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I'm trying to run some tests for a few FTP Addresses using Internet Explorer and FileZilla.

It's my first time working with a FTP Protocol, so probably I've skipped some steps.

My first attempt was to connect via Internet Explorer to two ftp servers

ftp://sft.if.usp.br/

ftp://ftp.cetip.com.br

Both worked perfectly, but when I try to connect using FileZilla, I've got the following error (Using port 20 and 21)

[image: FileZilla]

I'm under a corporate proxy for http and https.

Any idea about what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is. How can I code something if it doesn't even connect to the server?

Comment: I've helped you by suggesting that you should ask elsewhere. You won't get an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is configured to use your companies proxy and in fact issues an HTTP Request to the proxy requesting the URL `ftp://xyz.com`. The proxy then opens an FTP connection to the server and presents the result in a HTTP Response to the client.

FileZilla is a FTP Client which means that it will connect to the server using FTP. This fails due to firewalls blocking your request.

You need to find out if your company proxy also supports to proxy native ftp (client talks ftp to proxy, proxy talks ftp to server) and in that case configure filezilla accordingly.